# Can only see tables on linked server via administrator. Not as SQL server user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have two database servers. One on the office computer and one on the webserver. There is a secure encrypted tunnel between the two computers over the internet.
A SQL Server user has been set up on the webserver pc to allow access to the tables I need.

On the office pc there is a local account that needs access to those linked tables.

A linked server is setup between the computers. From the sysadmin interface in SQL Server Management Studio I can browse the tables at free will on the linked server.

but if I log in as the SQL Server user and I try test connection

```
===================================

The test connection to the linked server failed.

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(String cmd)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LinkedServer.TestConnection()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.LinkedServerConnectionTest.Invoke()

===================================

Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.5058&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=7416&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: SERVER\INSTANCE
Error Number: 7416
Severity: 16
State: 2
Procedure: sp_testlinkedserver
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
```

**What have I tried so far**

- Adding the local and remote user details to the Linked server properties  window.
- Adding default security context "Be made using this security context"

How can I set it up so the SQL Server user can use the linked server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that the user ID needs to be defined in the remote connection string.

From https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/03/10/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists/

> Cause: When creating a linked server with the parameter @provstr and
>   you use a local SQL Server non-admin or non-Windows account, you have
>   to add the parameter “User Name”   into the @provstr
>
> Resolution : Add “User ID=Username” into the provider string on your
>   linked server
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N’LinkServerName’,
>   @provider=N’SQLNCLI’,@srvproduct = ‘MS SQL Server’,
>   @provstr=N’SERVER=serverName\InstanceName;User ID=myUser‘
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N’LinkServerName’,
>   @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N’False’, @rmtuser = N’myUser’,
>   @rmtpassword = N’*****’

In total my setup string looked like this(with extra details for setting up the connection over the internet.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LINKEDSERVERNAME', @srvproduct=N'SQL_SERVER', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @provstr=N'SERVER=SERVER\INSTANCE;User ID=webuser', @datasrc=N'www.domain.com'
```

Small note, my webserver doesn't have an instance name, so I left the '\INSTANCE' part out of the connection string build up.

Note 2: The documentation states @srvproduct='MS SQL Server' but my 2012 sql server only accepts SQL_SERVER instead.